# strip zeros for BigDecimal only for after the decimal point in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

`stripTrailingZeros()`

```
new BigDecimal("4.0000").stripTrailingZeros();
#=> "4" (OK)

new BigDecimal("40.00000").stripTrailingZeros();
#=> "4E+1"
```

Can I obtain `40` in the second example by using stripTrailingZeros?
I mean, I want zero which is after the decimal point to disappear.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please do not alter the fundamental nature of the question after asking it and especially after getting an answer. Your recent edits *changed* the nature of the question from "I want zero which is after the decimal point to disappear" to something very different, invalidating existing answers. Rather than change the question, ask a new one.

Comment: Hi, @Bohemian. Thank you for the advice and sorry for the confusion.  I rollbacked the question changes, and I will ask in a  new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stripTrailingZeros()` returns a `BigDecimal`, but you want it to be *rendered* without zeros, so you want the `int` version of your `BigDecimal`:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("40.00000").intValue()); // "40"
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I want to preserve decimal digits if it's not zero. I mean that when input is "40.2000", output has to be "40.2",

Comment: As per comment to your question, don't change the nature of the question; ask a new question. Both the title "...after the decimal point" and the text in the question "I want zero which is after the decimal point to disappear" definitely mean truncating to integer. There is no other interpretation.

Comment: @user16012143 Note this answer works for your specific example (at least as currently worded), but [be warned](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue()) – "_[...] any fractional part of this BigDecimal will be discarded, and if the resulting "BigInteger" is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude and precision of this BigDecimal value as well as return a result with the opposite sign_".

Comment: [Like this?](https://rextester.com/IHYD53553)